# NTP - Disable timesyncd and enable NTP

Tags: ubuntu, ntp

I have installed ntp on ubuntu 16.04 but when I run `timedatectl` it doesn't show NTP. It shows `systemd-timesyncd` in the output.

I ran the command `sudo systemctl disable systemd-timesyncd; sudo systemctl stop systemd-timesyncd; sudo systemctl enable ntp;`

How do I set ntp for timedatectl?

I even tried `timedatectl set-ntp true` but still it doesn't show under `timedatectl` output.

```
root@host001:~# timedatectl
                      Local time: Fri 2020-05-08 16:00:59 UTC
                  Universal time: Fri 2020-05-08 16:00:59 UTC
                        RTC time: Fri 2020-05-08 16:00:59
                       Time zone: UTC (UTC, +0000)
       System clock synchronized: no
systemd-timesyncd.service active: no
                 RTC in local TZ: no
```

I was expecting output like below (as seen in others post) where NTP is shown instead of `systemd-timesyncd`

```
                      Local time: Fri 2020-05-08 16:00:59 UTC
                  Universal time: Fri 2020-05-08 16:00:59 UTC
                        RTC time: Fri 2020-05-08 16:00:59
                       Time zone: UTC (UTC, +0000)
                       Network time on: no
                       NTP synchronized: yes
                       RTC in local TZ: no
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
systemctl disable --now systemd-timesyncd
systemctl enable --now ntp
```

Or as Ubuntu and Red Hat are dismissing ntpd as legacy for some reason, [chrony is an option](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/network-ntp)

```
systemctl enable --now chrony
```

Read the [timedatectl man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/systemd-timesyncd.service.8.html), (this version of) set-ntp only controls systemd-timesyncd. Being a SNTP client, it won't discipline the system clock like a proper NTP. I consider this command a little misleading, and manage the time sync service units directly.